# Caesar Cipher Algorith Shifting C

Tags: c, algorithm, encryption

So I was writing a C program to make use of caesar algorithm using a custom table, where I will give the table and shifting will be done using that table e.g the text "abc" according to table "abc" with key=1 should be ciphered as bca, however i am having difficulty on the last characters if key+index of letter is higher than the length of the table stored here is my code

```
void encrypt (char table[],char entext[],char text[],int key)

{


     int i,j;

     int k = strlen(table);

     //int result = (key + k);
     for (i=0;i<strlen(table);++i)
     {
         j = 0;
         if (text[i]!='\0')
         {
             while (text[i]!=table[j])
             {
                   j++;
             }
             if ((j+key)>k)
             {
                j=(j+key)%k;
                //j = (result - j);
             }
             else
                 j = j + key;

             entext[i] = table[j];
         }
     }
     entext[i+1] = '\0';
     puts(entext);
}

int main()

{    

    char table[100] , text[100] , entext[100] , c;

    int i , j , key;
    printf("Enter the text : ");
    gets(text);
    printf("Enter the table : ");
    gets(table);
    printf("Enter the key : ");
    scanf("%d",&key);
    encrypt(table,entext,text,key);
    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: What is the problem? The only error I can spot is "if ((j+key)>k)" should be "if ((j+key)  >=  k)" (not to mention this check is completely unnecessary since you are using mod).

Comment: For debugging purposes you should hardcode the input data, so you don't have to enter painfully it each time you run the program.

Comment: @MichaelWalz or just have the data in a file and redirect the input

Comment: edit : wonderful i cant believe i missed the equality sign there and was eating my brains for so long , ty davir :D
I am new here so idk how to mark is as solved or vote for people

Comment: You could ask @davir to post an answer saying basically the same as his comment, which you could then mark as the 'accepted' answer, although, since the problem was a simple typographical / logic error, it might not be particularly helpful to future visitors, so you could probably also just delete it.

Comment: I wasn't sure if that was really the problem, but since it is I will write a proper answer. I agree with @Dukeling though, you could delete it if you don't have any sentimental attachment to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ((j+key)>k)
```

should be

```
if ((j+key)>=k)
```

Besides, this check is completely unnecessary because of how mod works. I will take the liberty to rewrite your code so it looks nicer:

```
void encrypt (char table[],char entext[],char text[],int key)
{
     int i,j;
     int k = strlen(table);

     //int result = (key + k);
     for (i=0;i<strlen(table);++i)
     {
         if (text[i]!='\0')
         {
             for(j=0; text[i] != table[j] ;j++);

             entext[i] = table[(j+key)%k];
         }
     }
     entext[i+1] = '\0';
     puts(entext);
}
```

I believe you could make this "table" lookup more efficient by indexing the value of the char itself, but unless you are dealing with pretty big input, this won't really make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
void encrypt (char table[], char entext[], char text[], int key) {
    int i,j;
    int k = strlen(table);

    for (i=0;text[i];++i){
        for(j=0;table[j] && text[i]!=table[j];++j)
            ;
        if(table[j]=='\0')//character not find at table
            entext[i] = text[i];//Not slide. // or Error?
        else {
            j += key;
            if(j>=k)
                j -= k;//j = j % k
            entext[i] = table[j];
        }
    }
    entext[i] = '\0';
    puts(entext);
}
```